# How to force a system of linear equations to return a non-trivial solution instead of the trivial one when finding the eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

When you've found the eigenvalues for a matrix A. And insert each eigenvalue into the relation: $(A-\lambda I) = 0$ and row reducing to echelon form for each one.

In the situations where you end up with the trivial solution, in other words the zero vector, it can't be used as an eigenvector by definition.

So how can you force the system to return a non-trivial solution, when you must have that in order to find the eigenvectors?

Comment: The RREF will be singular (contain a row of $0$'s). This will allow you to pick a parameter $t$ such that $(A-\lambda I)(tv) = 0$ for all $t$ and some $v\ne0$. Where exactly is your problem?

Comment: If you don't get a non-trivial eigenvector by the usual row reduction techniques, it's time to look for the arithmetical mistake you have made (either in finding the alleged eigenvalue, or in doing the row reduction).

Comment: I'm wondering cause I've heard somewhere that a computer program can return a non-trivial solution in those kinds of situations, so I was wondering if that really is true and if so, what's the method.

Comment: A computer program can return a nontrivial answer when there isn't a nontrivial answer because a computer can make mistakes, only the kind of mistake a computer makes is round-off error.